# Using angular 4 with esri-loader

Tags: angular, esri

I am planning to work on GIS based application using **esri (ArcGIS) with Angular 5**. I can find sample code of esri with AngularJS (Angular 1) but couldn't get hold of sample code of esri with Angular 4 or 5. I tried to search on YouTube as well but I guess I couldn't find any.

Can you guys help in pointing me in the right direction ?

Thanks.

Comment: Angular 4 or 5 or 6

Comment: With a quick look I did not find sth either, only [this](https://github.com/jwasilgeo/angular2-esri-playground) which has been archived and seems out of maintenance. Why don't you try using Leaflet or Openlayers instead?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already discovered this but for others, esri-loader is for lazy-loading esri types...https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader

There have been significant changes to both angular and the dependent typescript version between angular 4 and 8 (typescript 3.3).  You may actually find it easier to upgrade your project to angular 7 or 8 than to try to make the ESRI types compatible with an older version of angular or typescript. I am using 7 and typescript 3.2.4. esri-loaded appears to be referencing typescript   "typescript": "^3.3.4000" in the gitlab repo.

Here is my current project package.json with a working map and esri types for in angular 7 reference:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.212",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.12"+,
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.12",
    "@clr/angular": "^1.1.2",
    "@clr/icons": "^1.1.2",
    "@clr/ui": "^1.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.12.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "esri-loader": "^2.10.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
```

https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/tree/master/4.x/typescript